# Form with multiple submit buttons directing to different URL

Tags: html, forms, django-templates

I want to have a form with two submit buttons `Check In` and `Cancel` as following:

```
<div id="table-checkin-form">
  <form class="checkin-form-container" method="post">
    {{ checkin_form.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <a href="site_1">
      <button type="submit" class="button-table-checkin">Check In</button>
    </a>
      <button type="submit" class="button-table-checkin-cancel">Cancel</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

When `Check In` button is clicked, I would like to direct to the url `site_1`. If `Cancel` is clicked, do nothing (i.e. just close the form and stay on the same page). But the above does not work. In either case, the form closes without going to `site_1`.

But if I put the url `site_1` in

```
<form class="checkin-form-container" method="post" action="site_1">
```

then clicking both buttons will bring me to that `site_1`.

How should I implement this situation? Thanks.

Comment: It's better to use type="button" for the "Cancel button".So it will not submit the form to your action URL
 <button type="button" class="button-table-checkin-cancel">Cancel</button>

Comment: Thanks, all. I have just found this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256469/two-different-submit-buttons-in-same-form-in-django) with a good working solution for the exact same situation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can add the link to "site_1" directly into the creation of the button.

```
<button type="submit" class="button-table-checkin" onclick="location.href='Site_1'">Check In</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but u need to write the anchor tag inside the button then it will work.

```
<div id="table-checkin-form">
    <form class="checkin-form-container" method="post">
        {{ checkin_form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" class="button-table-checkin"> <a href="site_1">Check In</a></button>
        <button type="submit" class="button-table-checkin-cancel">Cancel</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can replace an `<a>` instead one of your buttons:

```
<button type="submit" class="button-table-checkin">Check In</button>
<a class="button-table-checkin-cancel" href="site_2">Cancel</a>
```

or add onclick to `<a>`